# How to get value from row for particular entity python

Tags: python, dataframe

Fetch the age by specific name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

I wants to get `'Age'` for `df['Name'] == 'Krish'`

Comment: Do you have to use a dataframe? So much easier (and **much** faster if you just work with the dictionary)

Comment: My input is a dataframe and output should be a single value i.e. 19

Comment: Your question clearly shows that you have a dictionary that you convert to a dataframe for no apparent reason

Comment: DO you have any solution for it. ignore about dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Name']=='Krish','Age'].values[0]
```

If you wish to get answer in int/str/float convert it to `list` and then show the first value by `[0]`

```
df.loc[df['Name']=='Krish','Age'].tolist()[0]
```

Comment: its working but output is a dataframe. I want single value i.e. 19

Comment: You can add `.values[0]` at last

Comment: Output is in array i.e. ['19'] but I want it in int,/float/str

Comment: @ShriganeshPatil check the updated code.